# To get value from dropdown list in JSP in case the value is a member of another class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, dropdown

How it would be better to get value from dropdown list in JSP in such case? Now 400 status error appears after pressing Submit button. I tried to search for the solution in Google, but there was no any variant which would helped me.

There are some fragments of code, which belongs to this issue. 
First class:

```
    public class Item1 {
    private int id;
    private Item2 item2; 

    //getters, setters
}
```

Second class:

```
    public class Item2 {
    private int id;
    private String description; 

    //getters, setters
}
```

First class controller:

```
@Controller
public class Item1Controller {
@Autowired
private Item1DAO item1DAO;
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveItem1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveItem1 (@ModelAttribute Item1 item1) {
    item1DAO.addOrUpdateCourse(item1);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/item1List");
}
}
```

JSP Form:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add New Item1</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form method="POST" action="/saveItem1" modelAttribute="item1">
    <table>
        <form:hidden path="id"/>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="Item2">Item2</form:label></td>
            <td>
    <form:select path="item2">
        <form:option value="null">No Item2</form:option>
        <form:options items="${item2List}"/>
    </form:select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
      <input type="submit" value="Save Item1"/>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put "get" and "set" methods (public) into the Item classes. A public constructor would be a good thing.
I would try to write the same path attribute value: description

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple mistakes in the form `path`s. Each must reference a simple field, not a complex object.

For example, you need:

```
<form:input path="item2.description"/> <!-- not path="description", no description in the Item1 model -->
<form:label path="item2.id">           <!-- not "Item2" by itself, and wrong case -->
<form:select path="item2.id">          <!-- not "item2" by itself -->
```

Comment: I am very sorry, I have made mistake in this code example. Item1 class has no field named description.

Comment: You still can't use `path="item2"` anywhere, as it's an Object, not a field. You have to set a field in item2, like `path="item2.id"`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped me.